# Is a comeager set also comeager with respect to any closed set containing it?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $Y,Z$ be two subsets of $X$. If $Z$ is comeager in $\overline Y$ and $Z\subseteq Y$ then $Z$ is comeager in $Y$ too?

Comment: Note that $X$ isn’t actually relevant here. To change the notation, you have a space $X$, a dense subset $D$ of $X$, and a set $Z\subseteq D$ that is comeagre in $X$, and you want to know whether $Z$ is comeagre in $D$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes I think you're right but since I have an answer with this notation I'm not going to change it. Sorry, do you agree with the answer? thank you

Comment: It isn’t quite right, because $Z$ need not be the intersection of countably many dense open sets. It can be fixed, because $Z$ does need to contain such an intersection as a subset. I’ve written up a more careful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Z$ is comeagre in $\operatorname{cl}Y$, $(\operatorname{cl}Y)\setminus Z=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$, where each $A_n$ is nowhere dense in $\operatorname{cl}Y$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $G_n=(\operatorname{cl}Y)\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n$; each $G_n$ is a dense open set in the relative topology that $\operatorname{cl}Y$ inherits from $X$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=G_n\cap Y$; each $U_n$ is open in the relative topology that $Y$ inherits from $\operatorname{cl}Y$, which is the same as the relative topology that it inherits from $X$. Moreover, each $U_n$ is dense in $Y$. (Why?) Thus, $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ is comeagre in $Y$. But

$$\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n&=Y\cap\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n\\
&=Y\cap\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\big((\operatorname{cl}Y)\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n\big)\\
&=Y\cap\left((\operatorname{cl}Y)\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}A_n\right)\\
&=Y\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}A_n\\
&\subseteq Y\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\\
&=Y\cap Z\\
&=Z
\end{align*}$$

and a superset of a comeagre set is comeagre, so $Z$ is comeagre in $Y$ as well.

Comment: sorry why $Y\setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n=Y\cap Z$ ? thank you very much.

Comment: I think only the following inclusion is true: $Y\setminus \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n\subseteq Z$. Indeed $(cl Y)\setminus Z=\bigcup_nA_n$ implies $Y\setminus Z\subseteq \bigcup_nA_n$ that implies $Y\subseteq \bigcup_nA_n\cup Z$, namely $Y\setminus \bigcup_nA_n\subseteq Z$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Richard: $$Y\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=(Y\cap\operatorname{cl}Y)\setminus \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n= Y\cap\left(\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\right)= Y\cap Z\;.$$

Comment: ok thank you, just for curiosity, was my last comment correct? I mean that series of inclusions which prove that $Y\setminus \bigcup_nA_n\subseteq Z$...

Comment: @Richard: Yes, it’s correct; it just doesn’t say as much as can actually be proved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

By definition, Z is the intersection of countably many open dense sets, $Z=\bigcap_n Z_n$. Be careful that $Z_n$ are open in the (subspace) topology on $\bar{Y}$ inherited by $X$.

Now consider $Z'_n=Z_n\cap Y$. Since $Z\subset Y$ and $Z=\bigcap_n Z_n$, it follows thatr $Z=\bigcap_n Z'_n$. Also, the $Z_n'$ are open in the (subspace) topology on $Y$ and they are dense in $Y$, because the $Z_n$ are dense in $\bar{Y}$.

Comment: sorry why are $Z_n$ open in the topology on $\overline Y$? thank you

Comment: similarly, why $Z_n'$ are open in $Y$ ? Since $Z_n'=Z_n\cap Y$ the $Z_n$ should be open in $X$ in order to make $Z_n'$ open in $Y$.

Comment: the answer to the second question probably is the following: if $Z_n$ is open in $\overline Y$ then $Z_n=O\cap \overline Y$ where $O$ is an open of $X$. So $Z_n'=Z_n\cap Y=O\cap \overline Y \cap Y=O\cap Y$ since $Y\subseteq \overline Y$ and so $Z_n'$ is open in $Y$.
However, I really don't understand why $Z_n$ is open in $\overline Y$.

Comment: Since a nowhere dense set in $\overline Y$ is not necessarily closed in $\overline Y$ I can't see why $Z$ is equal to $\bigcap_n Z_n$ as you said. If $Z$ is not equal to that set I think the proof does not work. At the same time surely $Z$ contains the set $\bigcap_n Z_n$.

Comment: @Richard: What is the definition of a comeager/meager set you were given?

Comment: ok probably with the observation that $Z$ contains $\bigcap_n Z_n$ the proof still works because in that way the complement of $Z$ is contained in the complement of $\bigcap_n Z_n'$ which is a meager set of $Y$, and so also the complement of $Z$ is meager in $Y$. Is this ok?

Comment: Ioannis a meager set is the union of countably many nowhere dense sets. A comeager set is the complement of a meager set.

Comment: You have to unravel the definition: A set M is meager is $M=\cap_n M_n$ where $M_n$ is nowhere dense. I.e. the closure of $M_n$ has empty interior. Consider the complements $M_n^c$. They have dense interiors. The sets $Z_n$ from my answer correspond to the interiors of the $M_n^c$ for you. They are open and dense, and their intersection is contained in $Z$.

Comment: First of all you meant $M=\bigcup_nM_n$ right? Secondly, I agree with this last observation. So also my observations are true, aren't they?

Comment: Yes $M$ is the union not intersection. Your observations look correct.